# Connecting to Lambda service using ec2 inside a private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to run the command “aws lambda list-functions” from an ec2 inside my private subnet that I connected to using a bastion host. The lambda has been deployed to the same VPC and private subnet, but when I try to run the command it times out. They are in the same region, and I have been able to connect to some of my other services within this ec2 but can’t connect to my lambda service endpoint.

I tried connecting from an ec2 inside a public subnet and that worked fine, but can't connect from ec2 inside the private subnet.

Comment: Solved. Needed to set up the endpoint manually in VPC, for s3 it was automatic.

Comment: Did the answer help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options for that:

1. Setup [NAT gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) in a public subnet along with route tables entries directly internet traffic in a private subnet to the NAT.
2. Setup [VPC interface endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpce-interface.html) for lambda so that you can connect to the lambda service without needing internet connectivity.

Comment: You mean interface endpoint, not internet.